# jquery popup error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Am running simple jquery code for opening the popup window in visual studio.Instead of opening in the new window it is navigating and wirking like hyperlinks.I dont know where am going wrong.my code is;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" >
     $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.examp').popupWindow({
    height:500,
    width:800,
    top:50,
    left:50
    });
    });
</script>  

<a href ="http://google.com" title="google.com" class ="examp">open</a>
```

this is really a simple problem but i cant found where am going wrong..

Comment: did you mean **$('.examp')** instead of $('.popup')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'ts most probably because you're not running popupWindow function inside [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.examp').popupWindow({
            height:500,
            width:800,
            top:50,
            left:50
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this helped me but it is not wotking out

Answer (score 1):

Nothing for the link is calling that function. Try this:

```
$(function() { //this is the ready function
    $('a.examp').click( function () { //when the link is clicked
        //popup code here
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, $.popupWindow binds the `click` event.